# Keeping a website secure by using an obscure domain name

Tags: php, security, dns

A non-technical, security-paranoid employee at work insists that an effective method of securing a website of ours, is to separate the application in to three parts; a front end, an API, and a backend management area for staff.

Both the API and the management system are on domain names that are just a random set of characters.

The application holds sensitive data, however, all of the applications are on the same server.

The problem I face is that debugging or adding features the application while it is in this state makes work extremely difficult, as it is unclear as to what part of the application does what. (There is no documentation and the previous developer has since left the company.)

He insists that future projects follow the same suite, with their own separate APIs and management areas, which I think will be unnecessary for a relatively simple application.

The second problem is that I know that security through obscurity is not necessarily security, and I don't see the point in using a domain that complicated to host part, or all of a website.

So my questions are this:

1) Is using an API like this going to carry any security benefits? Are there alternative ways that we can ensure the application and it's data is secure so that it does not compromise development speed.

2) Is using an obscure domain necessary to keep an application secure? Again, are there alternative methods that would be just as effective that wouldn't look as odd to future developers?

3) The management system is secured with a username and password. Would having the administration system be just as secure being on website.com/admin rather than randomcharacters.com?

Comment: Employee: how do i access admin area? ... HiPPO: You goto http://fd7fsdfcxc9sffgdfg9b0kjh9rewfr9sas9vhfghg.com got that... oh your not allowed to bookmark it incase its synced to an insecure place ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is using an API like this going to carry any security benefits? Are there alternative ways that we can ensure the application and it's data is secure so that it does not compromise development speed.

An API should be secured by an authentication mechanism such as an OAuth access token (AuthN). Who can do what on that API should then be determined by the claims in the access token (AuthZ). Authentication and Authorization should be thought of in these terms.

'I am this principal, I can prove this because I have a token that you have issued me and you can verify that only you could have issued it. I have a number of pieces of information that you can use to make decisions on what I'm allowed to do'

> 2. Is using an obscure domain necessary to keep an application secure? Again, are there alternative methods that would be just as effective that wouldn't look as odd to future developers?

No, using obscure domain names doesn't offer any level of security. They are just letters that are transformed into an IP address by a DNS entry - to use either my-website-address.com or hdsfiuycxzuyecgfr.com, you'd have to communicate that to someone and at that point they are equally secure!

> 3. The management system is secured with a username and password. Would having the administration system be just as secure being on website.com/admin rather than randomcharacters.com?

The questions to ask are, who are the users of the different parts of the system and who should have access to what? Is the front end application publicly visible on the internet and can it be used by various clients? Does the management system fall into the same category, or is that more of an internal tool? Identify the use cases for the components and consider whether you will secure them either by application logic, such as OAuth tokens, or infrastructure restrictions (e.g. only computers within a particular IP address range / subnet can access the management tool). It's usually a combination of both application and infrastructure security that provides the best level of protection.

Having the front end application and the management tool hosted as different applications may allow you to apply different security boundaries around them, which could be useful.

However, it's a matter of determining who your threat actors are and designing accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

An obscure domain name just needs to leak *once* somewhere; as soon as any attacker gets wind of the domain name, it ceases to be obscure and does not provide any benefit whatsoever. If you have a public website which makes API calls to the "obscured" backend, then that domain name is already being well publicised.

No, there's virtually no point in using an obscure name for the sake of security. If your API is insecure and allows unauthorised access, *that* is your security weak point; not the fact that the domain name might be known.